# can't find setJoinMode in PySide.QtSql

Tags: python, pyqt4, pyside, qtsql

in PyQt4 I can use the code below

```
self.mainModel = QSqlRelationalTableModel(self)
self.mainModel.setTable('Matches')
self.mainModel.setJoinMode(QSqlRelationalTableModel.LeftJoin)
```

but in PySide it gives me that QSqlRelationalTableModel has no attribute setJoinMode

is there any equivalent to it in PySide?
I am using PySide 1.2.1 on ubuntu 14.04

Comment: It would appear not (it's also missing in PySide-1.2.4). The function just sets an internal flag, so there's no way to work around it.

Comment: But I think it is not insignificant to be missing in pyside, logically it has to be some alternative way to do it

Comment: You can try raising an issue on the PySide bug tracker or mailing list. If it is trivial to implement it might not take too long for them to fix, but there are not many people left maintaining the project unfortunately.

Comment: @MohamedYousof. It's obviously a bug, so logic doesn't apply here.

Comment: So I think I have to move to PyQt instead, thanks for your comments